# Eclipse, Git and Assembla

Tags: eclipse, git

Somebody could say me how can use Eclipse with Git to work with a repository at Assembla? Assembla has a team, where everybody has their username and password. How can I use these information to access to my Assembla repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need your Assembla login/password to declare an Assembla Git repo in your Eclipse.

Each Assembla project needs its own private/public SSH key (See "[Different SSH keys for different projects](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/breakoutdocs/wiki/Different_SSH_keys_for_different_projects) "), which means you will use those projects like you would with GitHub projects (as illustrated in "[Egit Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#github)" and "[Eclipse SSH Configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration) ").

Except you will use addresses like `git@git.assembla.com:yourspace.git`.

Comment: Other considerations when working with Assembla repos: http://forum.assembla.com/forums/3/topics/2402 and http://forum.assembla.com/forums/2-Subversion/topics/3233-How-to-clone-a-public-git-repo-into-assembla

Comment: This means, every user allowed in the repo of Assembla, only need the SSH key in their Assembla account?

Comment: @BrallanAguilar: yes. Their account is for their Assemble profile. Their SSH key is for a specific Assembla project

Answer (score 0):

Assembla stopped supporting eclipse. At the beginning of June 2013 have been amended to preclude the use assembla with mylyn. This they said to me officially.